# SQL Server xml column filtering

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005, sqlxml

I have a SQL Server table with xml column. Xml column has the following xml data.

```
<organisation>
    <organisation id="1"> <p> Content by Interviewee1 </p1> <p> Interviewee1 is talking about organisation-1 </p1> </organisation>
    <organisation id="2"> <p> Content by Interviewee2 </p1> <p> Interviewee2 is talking about organisation-2 </p1> </organisation>
    <organisation id="1"> <p> Content by Interviewee3 </p1> <p> Interviewee3 is talking about organisation-1 </p1> </organisation>
</organisation>
```

I need to filter by organisation id. for example, if I filter by Id = 1, then the following xml is expected.

```
<organisation>
    <organisation id="1"> <p> Content by Interviewee1 </p1> <p> Interviewee1 is talking about organisation-1 </p1> </organisation>
    <organisation id="1"> <p> Content by Interviewee3 </p1> <p> Interviewee3 is talking about organisation-1 </p1> </organisation>
</organisation>
```

Comment: Do you mean you need to filter for a `SELECT` or are you trying to actually **update** the column and filter the XML in the process?

Comment: I need to filter. When someone says, get all the interview for organisation id = 1, then I need to get the interview data for org id = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (X XML)

INSERT INTO @T
        ( X )
VALUES  ( '<organisation>
    <organisation id="1"> <p> Content by Interviewee1 </p> <p1> Interviewee1 is talking about organisation-1 </p1> </organisation>
    <organisation id="2"> <p> Content by Interviewee2 </p> <p1> Interviewee2 is talking about organisation-2 </p1> </organisation>
    <organisation id="1"> <p> Content by Interviewee3 </p> <p1> Interviewee3 is talking about organisation-1 </p1> </organisation>
</organisation>'
          )

DECLARE @ID INT = 1


SELECT X.query('<organisation> 
                {for $o in /organisation/organisation
                where $o[@id=sql:variable("@ID")]
                return $o
                } </organisation>' )
FROM @T
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another...I added the CDATA tags to your XML nodes to preserve the html tags, but I don't know if this is an option for you.  Hope it helps (the first answer submitted by Stuart Ainsworth looks cleaner and better than this one though)

```
DECLARE @columnData XML =
'<organisation>
    <organisation id="1"> <![CDATA[ <p> Content by Interviewee1 </p> <p> Interviewee1 is talking about organisation-1 </p> ]]></organisation>
    <organisation id="2"> <![CDATA[ <p> Content by Interviewee2 </p> <p> Interviewee2 is talking about organisation-2 </p> ]]></organisation>
    <organisation id="1"> <![CDATA[ <p> Content by Interviewee3 </p> <p> Interviewee3 is talking about organisation-1 </p> ]]></organisation>
</organisation>'

DECLARE @temporaryXMLtable TABLE (organisation XML)
INSERT INTO @temporaryXMLtable
SELECT 
fctn.arg.query('.')
FROM @columnData.nodes('/organisation/organisation')
fctn(arg)

DECLARE @filteredXML XML
SET @filteredXML = (SELECT 
        t.organisation.value('(organisation/@id)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS '@id',
        t.organisation.value('organisation[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
    FROM (SELECT organisation from @temporaryXMLtable WHERE (SELECT     organisation.value('(organisation/@id)[1]','VARCHAR(20)')) <> 2)
    t(organisation)
    FOR XML PATH('organisation'), ROOT('organisation'))

SELECT @filteredXML
```